# SqlDataReader poisition

Tags: vb.net

When the code reaches the loop what will be the position of the reader, is it suppose to be 0 or 1?  Why does it behave this way?

```
bool tag= sqlDataReader.Read();
if (tag)
{
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
```

Comment: This is very badly structured. First you should not name a variable SqlDataReader, second you simply use the While statement. It will not execute the nested statements if the reader is empty and if it contains rows then will continue until you reach the end. This is basic programming skills.

Comment: this is more or less pseudo code, naming was chosen to make it obvious for what it is...  I also never said I was using this code, I am trying to understand its behaviour.  This article uses the while loop so I am experimenting and learning, what is wrong with that?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When you create the reader via SqlCommand.ExecuteReader, the reader is not positioned on any row. You need a first call to Read and if the call is successful you are positioned on the first record. You continue your loop until the Read fails meaning there is no more records to retrieve. If you think about it this way it the most logical and requires less code.

Comment: @Bagzli: the reader does only know the current row (if any). It does not even know the previous or next. It can tell you if there is another row, but only after it tried to get it via `Read`. Remember that a `DataReader` streams the records directly from the database (in reality the reader probably reads a batch of results at a time, but that doesn't change my  principal message).

Comment: If you need a position you could fill a `DataTable` with a `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of position in a `DataReader`. You are always at the first position. It is forward-only. The `DataReader.Read` reads the next record and returns True if a row was read, or False if no rows were read.

So, to answer your question, If your `sqlDataReader` had 0 rows, `tag` will be False. In such a case it won't ever enter the `If` block and hence never reach the `While` statement. If it had one or more rows, then `tag` will be True, and your `While` loop will execute until all rows have been read from the DataReader.

Comment: According to article linked after my message, there are positions, so I am trying to understand if the position is incremented and saved when a first check is implemented.  "The default position of the SqlDataReader is before the first record. Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where the Reader is up to in the data set is irrelevant - it's either on a record or it's not.

Comment: @Bagzli, What I meant by `no concept of position` in my answer is that you can't move around to particular records (like go to 5th record directly etc.). Means you can't reference records by their position numbers. You can just take out only the top record from the Reader.

Comment: As an addendum, if you do want random access to the results of your query, use a ```SQLDataAdapter``` to fill a ```DataTable``` and then traverse that instead.